# Event handling in google piechart using php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I am using Google PieChart and displaying the data from my DB. Once the user clicks on the Slice, I want to read the data and pass it to the DB to fetch few data. I am unable to get the data from the google chart upon click event.

Kindly find the code below which am currently using,

```
var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);

// Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


chart.draw(piechartdata, {
  width: 700,
  height: 200,
  is3D: true,
  chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    function selectHandler() {
      var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
      if (selectedItem) {
        var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        alert('The user selected ' + topping);
      }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);    
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Kindly help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is code misplaced, in what should be the `options`

`chart.draw` wasn't properly closed

and recommend checking the `length` of `chart.getSelection()`
before accessing the array elements

see following snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var piechartdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

    var options = {
      width: 700,
      height: 200,
      is3D: true,
      chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
    };

    chart.draw(piechartdata, options);

    function selectHandler() {
      var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
      if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
        var topping = piechartdata.getValue(selectedItem[0].row, 0);
        console.log('The user selected ' + topping);
      }
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your instant reply, Unfortunately after inserting the given code snippet when i click on the chart it just hangs and there is no response. I am not able to click on any other slice.

Comment: Hi whitehat After incorporating the changes you have suggested, it gives me an error Cannot read property getValue of Undefined.

Comment: needed to replace `data` with `piechartdata` in `selectHandler` -- above answer works now...